# SQL SELECT to return a list of: (cols if the id exists)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Given a list of IDs, say user1, user2, user3; I need to construct a query that will return a list containing only those that are present in the database, say user1, user2.

My current implementation is as follows (invalid SQL statement):

```
String queryString = ""
                + "IF EXISTS (SELECT cols... "
                + "FROM table "
                + "WHERE userID "
                + "IN (" + ids + ")";
        if ( ! includeDeleted ) {
            queryString += " AND u.DELETED = 'N'";
        }
        queryString += ") BEGIN "
                + "SELECT cols... " 
                + "FROM table "
                + "WHERE userID "
                + "IN (" + ids + ")"
                ;
        if ( ! includeDeleted ) {
            queryString += " AND u.DELETED = 'N'";
        }
        queryString += " END";
```

Comment: Note: userID is not a primary key, but a unique string provided by a 3rd party to identify the user in their system.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the query:

```
select * FROM MYTABLE where USERID IN ('user1', 'user4', 'user3');
```

This is a [**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ef43e/3/0).

Then the code for creating a query with parameters:

```
String[] accountIds = {.... your IDs ...}

StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
query.append("FROM table t WHERE t.userID IN (");
    for (int i = 0; i < userIds.length; i++) {
        if (!query.toString().endsWith("(")) {
            query.append(", ");
        }
        query.append("?");
    }
    query.append(")");

    if ( ! includeDeleted ) {
        query.append(" AND t.DELETED = 'N'");
    }
```